# using multi mysqli object or one generic object

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, optimization, mysqli

In my server I have few databases (around 12 with each of them few tables). The question is, in a single php class, I need to do two queries in two differents databases. In question of optimisation, is it faster to do

One generic mysqli object and call the two queries on it :

```
$database = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password'); #see, no database selected

$query1 = "select * from database1.tableX";    
$res1 = $database->query($query1);

$query2 = "select * from database2.tableY";    
$res2 = $database->query($query2);
```

Or two mysqli differents objects for each database

```
$database1 = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database1');

$database2 = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database2');

$query1 = "select * from tableX";
$res1 = $database1->query($query1);

$query2 = "select * from tableY";
$res2 = $database2->query($query2);
```

Considering I have much more database in the same server; which solution is fastier ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first is better, so you are connecting to the database with only 1 object, giving the database inherit in the query. In the second you use 2 objects, wich will consume more resources.... But talking that the server could be a machine  with a lot of recources, that could not affect too much, in the momento you close the conection the object is taked by the garbage collector.

Edit 1). The controler mysqli, internally should take the squema that it needs. so I think you will not see the diference on speed.

Comment: Even if in this object i'll have databases I wont use (like database3, database4...) ?

Comment: you can use the same object and use     mysqli_select_db ( mysqli $link , string $dbname ) to select the other db for the second query

Comment: it's not like you will have in the object that databases, remember that when you connect to mysql there is a default schema, and if you make a query deffining the database you want to use like "database3.table" that will not affect on the speed.

Comment: So whatever option, if I close the connection after, its the same?